# Stata 12 - A Long Tab and Getting Past the "More" Automatically

Tags: stata, tabular

If I tab for values in Stata 12 and there is a long list of values, Stata 12 seems to pause and display More.  It seems to want me to press Return (or perhaps any value) in order to continue.  I did not notice this feature with earlier features of Stata, say Stata 11, meaning that when I would hit tab it would just display all of the values at once (presuming that the list was not too long and it did not result in an error).  Is there a way around this in Stata 12 in which I would not be prompted to hit Return for such a long list?

Comment: you have to do the same thing as @Dimitriy said even for `11`

Comment: This has been in Stata a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `set more off`.

Extra characters.....